# How do I Import issues, pull/merge requests, and comments from Gitlab to Github?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to import several repositories from Gitlab (free cloud) to Github (free cloud).  These include lots of issues, pull/merge requests, and comments that I don't want to lose.  Github's import button really only does the equivalent of cloning a repo -- issues, pull/merge requests, and comments don't get transferred.  Going the other direction, into Gitlab, this is supported, which is why I'm puzzled as to why this is so hard to do.

Here's what I've tried:

- https://github.com/piceaTech/node-gitlab-2-github.  This one seems to work, but is very slow and constantly runs into API calls-per-hour limits.  After a few hours, fewer than ten issues are imported and their timestamps are in the present, not when they were originally filed.
- https://github.com/actions/importer-issue-ops and https://github.com/actions/importer-labs.  These have been suggested as solutions, but I can't figure out how to actually use them.
- https://github.com/gavinr/github-csv-tools.  This one throws an error and aborts after importing the second issue.  Like with node-gitlab-2-github, timestamps are not correct.  For my test, I cloned a Github repository and pushed it back to Github with a different project name.  I then used this tool to pull the issues into a CSV file from the first repository and then used this tool again to push it into the second repository.

Comment: going the other direction into github is supported? do you mean going the other direction going into gitlab is supported?

Comment: Whoops!  You're right.  Fixed!

Comment: is this from cloud gitlab to cloud github or enterprise to enterprise or cloud to enterprise  etc? just update the question with that info it would be helpful as there are differences

Comment: Cloud to cloud.  Fixed.